# Deamon at startup

Tags: startup, services

How can we run httpd service at startup ?
( this task will activate a startup script , that you have written, to start the "httpd" deamon ( /us/local/sbin/httpd ) )

Comment: Since httpd is Apache, usually, why don't you simply install Apache from the repositories (`sudo apt-get install apache2`), which will the take care of startup?

Answer (score 0):

Use systemd to set it to start on boot.

```
sudo systemctl enable httpd
```